# Accessing pods through ClusterIP

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I want to create a cluster of RESTful web APIs in AWS EKS and be able to access them through a single IP (allowing kubernetes to load balance requests to each). I have followed the procedure explained the this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types) and have set up an example `nginx` deployment as shown in the following image:

[image]

The problem is that when I access the example `nginx` deployment via `172.31.22.183` it works just fine, but when I try to use the cluster IP `10.100.145.181` it does not yield any response in such a way that it seems to be unreachable.

What's the purpose of that cluster ip then and how can I use it to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the purpose of that cluster ip then and how can I use it to
> achieve what I need?

`ClusterIP` is local IP that is used internally in the cluster, you can use it to access the application.

While i think Endpoint IP that you got, is might be external and you can access the application outside.

> AWS EKS and be able to access them through a single IP (allowing
> kubernetes to load balance requests to each)

For this best practice is to use the ingress, API gateway or service mesh.

Ingress is single point where all your request will be coming inside it will be load balancing and forwarding the traffic internally inside the cluster.

Consider ingress is like Loadbalancer single point to come inside the cluster.

**Ingress** : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

AWS Example : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/

Comment: You mean I have to collect Endpoint IPs and put them behind HA proxy to do load balancing (without using Ingress) and there's no other way to get one loadbalancing IP?

Comment: You can use ingress and have to create the cluster ip service for each deployment. Ingress will point to service. If you will watch diagram you will get idea, ingress is load balancer you will apply yaml rule in ingress and it will forward traffic to service with cluster ip.

Comment: But I faced a lot of problems with ingress before and for that reason I may not want to use it. So in this case, I have to put Endpoint IPs behind HA Proxy, right? and that means there's no other way to do it using Kubernetes only (ingress is an image running on kube)

Comment: yes ingress will be running one pod or in other word you can say you have to run ingress controller pod, nginx ingress controller is one example. you can install haproxy, service mesh and API gateway like KONG on k8s and it would be easy to resolve your issue.

Comment: you can follow aws example that i shared it's pretty easy and straight forward.

Comment: I understand that you are talking about `ingress` but let's forget about that option for now, like it does not exists. Then does it mean that the only way is to put the IPs behind HA Proxy?

Comment: yes right, that you can do it, however link you have shared have many details, not sure how you have configured endpoint but you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

`ClusterIP` is an IP that is only accessible inside the cluster. You cannot hit it from outside cluster unless you use `kubectl port-forward`

Comment: Can you provide an example command for the port-forward?

Comment: `kubectl port-forward -n {namespace} svc/{service} localport:targetport`

would connect localport on your machine to targetport on the cluster. So for your example, `kubectl port-forward -n default svc/nginx-service 80:80` will allow you to use http://localhost to access the service